# javscript async not returning back value

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to use javascript on a button press in which it will fetch a rest API.

My code is as below

```
  // coupon
  $('.coupon').click(function() {
    (async () => {

        
        const rawResponse = await fetch(`/getcoupons`, {
          method: 'GET'
        });
        console.log(rawResponse.text())
        var couponfield = document.getElementById("couponfield")
        couponflag = couponfield.value
        shoppingCart.addCouponCart(couponfield);
        displayCart();
    })();
```

However my console.log(rawResponse.text()) returns a

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

can I check where I'm going wrong because Im doing await for the response. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Just do `console.log(await rawResponse.text())`

Comment: please add `await` infront of it